# php echo iframe or image

Tags: php, html, sql, iframe, echo

Hey everyone I am having an issue with echoing an image or an iframe, the idea is there is an image link or an iframe in the same row in the database & i want to only echo what the string content is, if it echos the iframe there is a blank space of an image & underneath is the youtube video, if it echos the image the iframe does not show, they both currently echo the same row id labled url, I only want one to echo based on the string content instead of both echo's.

Here is the code I use to fetch the stuff, its only the echo area you want to pay attention to, I am not sure what kind of, if or else statement i could put in here.

```
< ?php

require_once("config.php");

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 4;

$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET 

    $offset";
    try {
      $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    if (count($results) > 0) {
      foreach ($results as $row) {

        echo '<li><kef>' . $row['title'] . '</kef></br>';  
        echo '<img src=' . $row['url'] . '></br>';     /*here */
        echo '<kef1>' . $row['url'] . '</kef1></br>';    /*and here*/
        echo '<kef2>' . $row['desc'] . '</kef2></br>'; 
        echo '<kef3>' . $row['tag'] . '</kef3></br> </br> </li>';
  } }
?>
```

This script is a get results php

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the code preview, i am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to save the data in different columns in the database. But if you want to keep the current structure would be able to check if the string contains HTML, then it is an iframe. Otherwise it is a link to the image.

```
<?php

    if($row['url'] == strip_tags($row['url'])) {
        //No HTML in string = link
        echo '<img src="' . $row['url'] . '" alt="" />';

    } else {
        //Contains HTML = iframe
        echo $row['url'];

    }

?>
```

This assumes that you in your database have saved the values as either `http://www.exempel.com` or `<iframe src =" http: // www ... ">`. If the iframe-value also consists only of a URL, you must use another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know whether the url is an image or video when you save them in the database then you could add another field for the media type. You could then use this in an if statement in your code, for example:

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo '<li><kef>' . $row['title'] . '</kef></br>';  

        if ($row['mediaType'] === 'image') {
             echo '<img src=' . $row['url'] . '></br>';     /*here */
        } if ($row['mediaType'] === 'video') {
            echo '<kef1>' . $row['url'] . '</kef1></br>';    /*and here*/
        }

        echo '<kef2>' . $row['desc'] . '</kef2></br>'; 
        echo '<kef3>' . $row['tag'] . '</kef3></br> </br> </li>';
    }
}
```